# God's attributes in the parallels between 1 Samuel and Esther

Tags: 1-samuel, attributes-of-god, esther

As [Dottard mentions](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/58198/27054)

> Haman in the Book of Esther was a descendant of the king Agag that Samuel executed (see 4 above).

In addition to that, Mordecai is linked with Saul as we read in 1 Samuel 9:1-2 (NASB)

> Now there was a **man of Benjamin** whose name was Kish the son of Abiel, son of Zeror, son of Becorath, son of Aphiah, son of a Benjaminite, a valiant mighty man. 2 He had a son whose name was Saul, a young and handsome man, and there was not a more handsome man than he among the sons of Israel; from his shoulders and up he was taller than any of the people.

and in Esther 2:5 (NASB)

> There was a Jew at the citadel in Susa whose name was Mordecai, the son of Jair, the son of Shimei, the son of Kish, **a Benjaminite**,

Interestingly their linkage is made clearer given that both of their parents are named "Kish". Yet, despite the similarity, one Benjamite succeeded to fulfill God's will towards Amalek whereas the other didn't.

What does this reveal us about God?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What does this reveal about God?

"God is love" (1 John 4:8, 16).

... and

"Love is patient, love is kind. ..." 1 Cor 13:4

God gave the wicked Amalekites a very long probation beginning at the time of the Exodus to the time of Esther - about 1000 years!  God is very patient and kind!

It also reveals that king Saul, despite his boasts to the contrary (1 Sam 15:7, 13) did not complete the job of destroying the Amalekites as instructed by God through the prophet Samuel.  This made things difficult for David and Esther later as we all know.

Comment: «This made things difficult for David and Esther later as we all know.», such an open-eyes and makes us not wanting to fail... Thank God for Jesus because it's only possible through Him (*simul justus et peccator*)